# Literature is closing — what questions should we migrate here?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions, questions, migration

Our sister site [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)  is [shutting down on May 4th](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/literature-is-closing) due to a lack of activity. (So are [Astronomy, Economics, Firearms, Healthcare IT and Theoretical Physics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).)

There may be some interesting questions at Literature (or even possibly the others) that would find a good home here at English Language and Usage.

If so, please flag the questions for moderator attention and suggest migration. I think the deadline for this is next Friday, 4th May.

---

PS See similar migration requests on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/literature-is-closing-what-questions-should-we-migrate-here) and [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/what-questions-should-we-salvage-scavenge-from-literature-se).

Comment: In this process, please keep in mind (and this isn't directed to anyone specific, just a general reminder to all) that "[c]riticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" are off-topic on our site as per the FAQ. That doesn't mean that there are no migrate-worthy questions, just that there are likely few.

Comment: This question captures two major problems with the StackExchange model: (1) segregating questions into topically-oriented sites is not a scalable approach, and (2) perfectly good questions get closed because someone with power (measured in participation points) objects for questionable (and often silly) reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is currently flagged:

- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/english-use-in-adventures-of-a-bystander-by-peter-drucker#question
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/933/why-does-juliet-ask-wherefore-are-thou-romeo-and-not-montague#question

To migrate:

Migrated:
 - https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/823/her-mind-was-less-difficult-to-develop-jane-austen#question

Rejected:

Comment: please edit this to designate which ones you want or don't want, i'll then edit it when posts are migrated.

Comment: interesting use of editing system XD.

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog - Yeah. I would have suggested ones people wanted be put in as "answers", so others can vote and/or comment on individual choices. Time's short though.

Comment: At least the first one seems too discussion based for ELU

Comment: I think the 3rd one would be worthy of a migrate.  The first one, I agree with simchona: surely not - it never really gets to an ELU-type question ("Can you read this book without a dictionary?").

Comment: @jr I agree with 3. In addition, 2 is more literary analysis of why a certain name was used, which isn't screaming "migrate" to me.